# Mobile site: getting rid of it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

Is there a way to (**permanently**) get rid of the mobile versions of the site? Periodically SE decides to take me to it on my iPod and then I have to go back to the full site—this has happened many many times already! If the site thinks I may have repented since the last time I asked it to take  me back to the full site, it could at least ask me...

Comment: I edited to clarify that the temporarily honoured request in going back to the full site is already known. In other words, [getting rid of may not mean getting rid of](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bETCusT5kNM).

Answer (score 8):

A fix will be deployed in the next production build (sometimes tonight or tomorrow). Your setting will no longer expire.